# Renaming columns with same name

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to rename three columns "Devolutiva" that has the same name but isn't working, can u guys help me understand what's happening?

First output

```
df_fields.columns
Index(['id', 'SPV', 'Estado', 'Produtos', 'Motivo', 'Observações',
       'Observações gerais', 'Devolutiva', 'Devolutiva', 'Devolutiva',
       'Centro de Custo 1'],
      dtype='object')
```

I tried this:

```
df_fields = df_fields.rename({df_fields.columns[7] : 'Devolutiva_Ind',
                              df_fields.columns[8] : 'Devolutiva_Log',
                              df_fields.columns[9] : 'Devolutiva_Com'})
```

Tried this:

```
df_fields = df_fields.rename({'Devolutiva' : 'Devolutiva_Ind',
                              'Devolutiva' : 'Devolutiva_Log',
                              'Devolutiva' : 'Devolutiva_Com'})
```

And also this:

```
df_fields = df_fields.rename({'Devolutiva_1' : 'Devolutiva_Ind',
                              'Devolutiva_2' : 'Devolutiva_Log',
                              'Devolutiva_3' : 'Devolutiva_Com'})
```

And it keep printing the same .columns output as above, so weird.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### why it doesn't work?

If you run the following in your python interpreter:

```
{'Devolutiva' : 'Devolutiva_Ind',
 'Devolutiva' : 'Devolutiva_Log',
 'Devolutiva' : 'Devolutiva_Com'}
```

you will realize that only the last value is kept:

```
{'Devolutiva': 'Devolutiva_Com'}
```

A dictionary **cannot** contain duplicate keys. So, you are actually just running:

```
df_fields.rename({'Devolutiva' : 'Devolutiva_Com'})
```

##### how to de-duplicate the column names?

You could use a helper generator:

```
def suffix():
    yield ''
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield f'_{i}'

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(suffix)

df.columns  = df.columns.map(lambda x: x+next(d[x]))
```

output:

```
df.columns

Index(['id', 'SPV', 'Estado', 'Produtos', 'Motivo', 'Observações',
       'Observações gerais', 'Devolutiva', 'Devolutiva_1', 'Devolutiva_2',
       'Centro de Custo 1'],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df_fiels.columns = ['id', 'SPV', 'Estado', 'Produtos', 'Motivo', 'Observações',
       'Observações gerais', 'Devolutiva_newName1', 'Devolutiva_newName2', 'Devolutiva_newName3', 'Centro de Custo 1']
```

Comment: Well, that worked. The rest of columns may vary, can't I rename just those three columns?

Comment: Then you can use normal list manipulation to detect and rename those columns. Once  your list of columns is modified accordingly, you can reassign the column names with the same method.